# How to display a colorbox only one time when a page loads

Tags: users, javascript

I have created a colorbox effect to show the login form when the home page loads using the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery.fn.colorbox(
    {href:"user/login/colorbox",open:true}
  ); 
});
```

Now I want to do the same to display a registration form, but this registration form should only be displayed one time.

Please can any one help me find a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing a cookie after showing the login form and checking if the cookie exists before that. For cookies there's a nifty jquery plugin as well - no big programming involved on your side.
HTH